# Optimize mysql query for date group

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

This my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_dates` (
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_log` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timest` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `test_dates`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`date`);

ALTER TABLE `test_log`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `emissione` (`timest`);
```

I have this query to count logs per date:

```
SELECT d.date, COUNT(l.id) 
FROM test_dates d
LEFT JOIN test_log l ON l.timest>=d.date AND l.timest<d.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
GROUP BY d.date
```

table **test_dates** is indexed in date colum and **test_log** table is indexed in timest column.

But explaining this query I got query type "ALL" and NULL key.

```
+-----+--------------+--------+-------------+--------+----------------+----------+----------+------+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+--+
| id  | select_type  | table  | partitions  | type   | possible_keys  |   key    | key_len  | ref  | rows   | filtered  |                     Extra                      |  |
+-----+--------------+--------+-------------+--------+----------------+----------+----------+------+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+--+
|  1  | SIMPLE       | d      | NULL        | index  | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY  | 3        | NULL |   705  | 100.00    | Using index                                    |  |
|  1  | SIMPLE       | l      | NULL        | ALL    | emissione      | NULL     | NULL     | NULL | 98256  | 100.00    | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2) |  |
+-----+--------------+--------+-------------+--------+----------------+----------+----------+------+--------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Why mysql cannot use table indexes?

Log tables has about 100000 rows and the query is very slow.

Comment: Presumably the query is slow? As a minimum, questions about query performance require CREATE statements for all relevant tables (and preferably sample data too), and the result of the EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 2):

Try running this as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT d.date,
       (SELECT COUNT(l.id) 
        FROM log l 
        WHERE l.timest >= d.date AND l.timest < d.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
       ) as cnt
FROM dates d;
```

MySQL is not very good when using indexes with `GROUP BY`.  Sometimes using a subquery can be a significant boost to performance.  Your table has the correct indexes.

Comment: Test at work (MySQL 5.6.26): no difference. Test at home (MariaDB 10.0.19): Huge difference. Maybe MySQL 5.7 is as good as MariaDB 10.

Comment: I confirm that I tested it with mysql 5.6.26

Answer (score 0):

If the index and correlated sub-query are not working for you, your better option may be to update your dates table and add a summary count column.  Then, when you do an insert into your logs table, you add 1 to your counter in the dates table for the date in question.  If no such record exists yet, add one and set its count to 1 since it is a new record.

Then, all you would need to do is select a sum() from your dates table based on the date range and never look at the details.   Once a given date IS selected for possible review, then you could query the underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it around.  First do an efficient `GROUP BY` on the second table (see subquery, below), then fill in the missing days (outer query):

```
SELECT  date,
        IFNULL(log.ct, 0) AS ct
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  DATE(timest) AS date,
                COUNT(*) AS ct
            FROM  test_log 
            GROUP BY date
      ) AS log
    RIGHT JOIN  test_dates AS d  USING(date);
```

If you want to limit the date range, add a `WHERE` clause in both the subquery and the outer query.