# Joining two tables with a Sum condition

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a query where I generate a sum on a value field based on selected IDs from that table:

```
SELECT Z,Sum(Z_N) FROM `TableA` 
WHERE `N_ID` in ('7703','7674','7689','7690','7691','7700','7719') 
group by Z 
having Sum(Z_N) > 65
```

However I need to grab that list of IDs from a second table dynamically which I've managed so far on its own as:

```
Select group_concat(N_ID) from Table2 where N2_ID ='7703'
```

The N2_ID='7703' will actually be a variable I push via code. Yet I'm trying to get the second query "inside" the first to replace the manual `('7703','7674','7689','7690','7691','7700','7719')`

Clearly (I think) this is some kind of join yet it escaped me on this Saturday morning.

Comment: Do you want **N_ID** list where **N2_ID = 7703** from **Table2** OR something else? (talking about the second query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subselect

```
SELECT Z,Sum(Z_N) FROM `TableA` 
WHERE `N_ID` in (Select N_ID from Table2 where N2_ID ='7703') 
group by Z 
having Sum(Z_N) > 65
```

Answer (score 1):

An `INNER JOIN` can filter your result.

```sql
SELECT TableA.Z,Sum(TableA.Z_N) 
FROM `TableA`
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.N_ID = TableA.N_ID
where Table2.N2_ID ='7703'
group by TableA.Z 
having Sum(TableA.Z_N) > 65
```

For performance you should have (at least) indexes on `Table2(N2_ID)` and `TableA(N_ID, Z)`. The indexes `Table2(N2_ID, N_ID)` and `TableA(N_ID, Z, Z_N)` might be even better, because the complete query would operate only on indexes.

Note: This works, if `Table2.N_ID` is unique (or primary key). If not, you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Which one is faster (SubQuery or INNER-JOIN, in this specific scenario)

Comment: @MalikAsif, i don't expect a difference in performance. But a JOIN shouldn't be slower on MySQL-Version >= 5

Comment: @MalikAsif, This [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401234/optimize-mysql-query-for-date-group) just came into my mind. So i'm not that sure about performance any more. You should test both solutions on big test data.

Comment: @Malik Asif I will test and report back, right now the subselect is (for me) slow, adds about 2 second on the .2 sec subquery. I'll check indexes then run/test both and update Question or Comments

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I have been unable to make this work, I just read the caveat; N_ID is not unique in either table. Each table utilizes that NID for multiple relationships.

Comment: I am happy that you are helping me. Thank you for the useful information.